# Ruby struct creation block cannot access variable outside the block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, block

Accessing the `default` variable inside the Struct creation block doesn't seem to work in this case:

```
default = 'test'
A = Struct.new(:a, :b) do
  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
    self.b ||= default
  end
end
```

It is throwing the following error:

```
'initialize': undefined local variable or method `default' for #<struct A a=2, b=nil> (NameError)
```

Can someone explain why this is happening and whether there is a work around?

(Tested on Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.1.2)

Comment: your `default` variable in another scope.

Comment: You need to make it available inside the scope of Struct, either change it to a global variable (not recommended) or a constant.

Comment: Your analysis is wrong: the variable *is* accessible inside the block. It is, however, *not* accessible inside the method definition. Only blocks are closures, method, class, and module definitions as well as scripts create empty scopes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `def` keyword starts new local variables scope, so `default` local variable isn't visible inside of it. The workaround is to use `define_method`, because the block you pass into it is closure:

```
default = 'test'
A = Struct.new(:a, :b) do
  define_method(:initialize) do |*args|
    super(*args)
    self.b ||= default
  end
end
a = A.new
a.b
# => "test"
```

Comment: I wonder how much it's an ok practice to solve scope problem like this.

Answer (score 0):

The `default` variable is out of the scope of the `initialize` method. I'd recommend you make it into a constant (rename it to DEFAULT) if you want to access it (unless, that is, you plan to change the default during program runtime, but I don't see why you'd do that, otherwise it wouldn't be named that way):

```
DEFAULT = 'test'
A = Struct.new(:a, :b) do
  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
    self.b ||= DEFAULT
  end
end

a = A.new(1)
p a.b #=> test
```

Comment: "The default variable is out of the scope of the A class." - not really, it's outside of `initialize` method definition scope.